# Run APScheduler and twilio webhook from one flask server

Tags: python, flask, twilio, apscheduler

I'm currently working on creating an SMS message service with Twilio, but I also want it to be able to send texts at certain times on its own. I'm looking into using APScheduler to do this, but haven't gotten it to work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

app = Flask(__name__)
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()


@app.route('/bot', methods=['POST'])
def bot():
    print("received incoming POST")
    incoming_msg = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    responded = False
    if 'quote' in incoming_msg:
        # return a quote
        r = requests.get('https://api.quotable.io/random')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = r.json()
            quote = f'{data["content"]} ({data["author"]})'
        else:
            quote = 'I could not retrieve a quote at this time, sorry.'
        msg.body(quote)
        responded = True
    if 'cat' in incoming_msg:
        # return a cat pic
        msg.media('https://cataas.com/cat')
        responded = True
    if not responded:
        msg.body('I only know about famous quotes and cats, sorry!')
    return str(resp)

async def job():
    print('hi')

scheduler.add_job(job, "interval", seconds=3)
scheduler.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run this, I'm able to send and receive texts, but the "hi" print causes an error message : `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'job' was never awaited`. Does anyone have advice on either addressing this bug or using a different stack to perform this function?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I just got it to work by removing the `async` part of the job function.